# Display Highest AND Lowest Values Sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SqlPlus and I am trying to display the highest AND lowest average salaries in all departments. So far I was able to display the highest salaries only but I can't seem to display the lowest salaries as well.

This is what I got so far

```
SELECT deptno AS "Dept. No", MAX(sal) AS "Salary"
FROM emp e
WHERE e.sal > (SELECT avg(sal) FROM emp)
GROUP BY deptno;
```

The output I am getting is

```
Dept. No   Salary
30         2850
20         3000
10         5000
```

I am trying to get

```
Dept. No   Salary
30         2850
30         950
20         3000
20         800
10         5000
10         1300
```

Oh and I am using the dept and emp table samples!

Comment: What do you mean by highest and lowest average salaries in all departments? Calculate the average for each department (each department has one average), and then from all these averages (one for each department), just show the highest and the lowest?

Comment: In any case: the query you wrote has a `where` clause, with two conditions connected by `and`, and the two conditions directly contradict each other; so clearly there will be zero rows selected regardless of anything else.

Comment: @mathguy I meant display the high AND low. For example; let's say the highest is $50 and the lowest is $20, I want to display both those values. So far I am only able to display the $50 value. I edited my question to show my expected output!

Comment: Remove `WHERE e.sal > (SELECT avg(sal) FROM emp)`. Then add `MIN(sal) AS "Min Salary"` next to `max`

Comment: @krokodilko Thank you!!! I don't know how this flew over my head!

Comment: Why do you have `where e.sal > (....)` - why do you need to compare to an average salary at all? What does your problem have to do with ANY average of ANYTHING?

Answer (score 1):

This query worked for me if anybody else has the same problem! :)

```
SELECT deptno AS "Dept. No", MAX(sal) AS "Highest Salary", MIN(sal) AS "Lowest Salary"
FROM emp
GROUP BY deptno;
```

Comment: Haha, the "same problem" would be to be confused :-) The task is easy: You want the minimum and maximum salary per department. And this almost translates word for word into SQL. The "problem" was that you thought you were looking for some avarage salaries instead, which has really nothing to do with the actual task.